# How do I use a button click to determine if a check button has been clicked/checked in order to run an executable? (with tkinter)

Tags: python, tkinter

The GUI itself works in the sense that it will display the text and both of the checkboxes, but when I check off a box and hit the "Click to start" button nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter
import os

window = tkinter.Tk()

window.title("Startup Menu")

tkinter.Label(window, text="Choose the applications to start:", justify=tkinter.LEFT, padx=20).pack()


# N
n_clicked = tkinter.IntVar()
n_check = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text="N", variable=n_clicked)
n_check.pack()
# S
s_clicked = tkinter.IntVar()
s_check = tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text="S", variable=s_clicked)
s_check.pack()



# Startup button that executes the selected applications
def click():
    if n_clicked == 1:
        os.startfile(r"(file location)")
    if s_clicked == 1:
        os.startfile(r"(file location)")


# Start selected applications button
start_up = tkinter.Button(window, text="Click to start", command=click).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: examine the value of `n_clicked` inside of `click` - it's not what you think it is. The first step in debugging is always to examine  your variables to see if they are what you think t hey should be. For example, add `print(n_clicked)` before your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tkinter variables use a `get()` and `set()` method to work with them.

```
if n_clicked.get():
```

Comment: thank you so much! that was exactly what I needed